# How to add dynamic row in grid edit form in custom module in magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, adminform, dynamic-rows

can any one idea for how to add dynamic row in add grid data form in Magento 2

[image]

I want to manage the app screen section for example in one section i add multiple banner data so how can i mange it

i know i manage it from dynamic row but how can i add dynamic row in admin grid form